# Display a series of dropdown lists with past dates in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using model forms in Django to allow the user to enter in their birthdate. I want to have the user select the date from a series of dropdown lists, one each for year, month, and day. Originally I thought that the SelectDateWidget would work. However that particular widget only displays dates in the future. I of course want to only display dates in the past.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SelectDateWidget` isn't only for dates in the future. If you want dates in the past, you need to pass a different `years` argument into your widget, otherwise it uses the current year. So within your form, just do:

```
SelectDateWidget(years=range(1985, datetime.date.today().year+10))
```

It basically accepts a list of years, and using the `range` function works pretty well for that.

You can see how the widget works [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/extras/widgets.py)